# Easily spinning Windows and Linux containers

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, docker, container

I'm thinking about setting up a CI/CD infrastructure for my team.
Since the components we're developing are on-premise and should run a different OSs, I'm thinking on spinning up Windows & Linux containers.
Clearly I could use Kubernetes and spin up some dockers, but then I'm limited to Linux and Windows 2016. Since I need to test even older versions of Windows such as Win 7, 8, & 10, I thought on spinning up VMs.
I've read that Kubernetes + RancherVM or Nomad can be used to spin up VMs but haven't tried it out.
Does anyone have experience it or had to develop something similar? I want to hear some info before spending days of research in the wrong direction.

Comment: You might find there are more people with experience of such things over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), if they allow questions without code, sorry I can't help more myself, I am only familiar with VS and Azure for CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Vagrant. Since VM deploy a provision can be automated. Virtual machines in VirtualBox and Hyper-V can be used.

Regards